# Top menu doesnot take the url key values as links

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have CMS pages with the url key values as shown
[image]

But in the top menu the

But in the front end top menu the links are not using the url keys.
For example the CMS page "gift registry" has url key "gift_registry". But the menu have link "gift-registry". So the page show 404 error

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity How chould you know this question is not related to programming? Are you well versed in Magento?

Comment: Because there is nothing in the question about programming. The question must be about programming. Can you explain what the programming issue is?

Comment: did you tried reindexing?